# pupetteer : can it run in SSH with no video card?

Tags: puppeteer

I installed pupetteer with npm on a Debian server

When I much it with node myscript.js

I got many depencies errors like ibX11-xcb.so.1, libx11-xcb1,libgail-common,libxss1...

I tried to install them with

```
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

And finally got that last error:

```
(node:17765) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[1127/220033.713091:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Is pupeteer working on debian 8 ?

Comment: Please include a sample of your script - how you're running puppeteer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a virtual X-Server called Xvfb.
However, latest chrome builds have headless mode (just start it with `--headless` flag). If, for some reason, chrome wont be suitable for you (it doesn't work with proxies in headless mode), you can try headless firefox (`-headless` flag) or phantomJS.

Comment: Problem is that the scrapping in headless mode does not work.  I guess the website has a kind of protection to avoid headless browser. Works fine in no headless mode and got anothet JS obfuscated content when trying to use headless mode.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it is happening. Try to set up browser's resolution and headers(especially user agent) explicitly.